# Express JS router sometimes returns 404 and sometimes 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use angular 2 and express js. So for all requests which is not css, images, js, video I send index.html file. My router code:

```
router.get(/\/(?!((.*\.html$)|(.*\.css$)|(.*\.mp4)|(.*\.woff)|(.*\.js$)|(.*\.map$)|(.*\.jpg$)|(.*\.jpeg$)|(.*\.png$)|(.*\.gif$))).+$/gmi,
  ensureConnect.ensureLoggedIn({ redirectTo: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res
      .set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
      .sendFile(../dist/index.html);
  });
```

For root router *'/'* it works perfect, but if I try open another page (e.g. *'/product/am-0596157134'*) it sometimes open page, but sometimes returns 404 (**Cannot GET /product/am-0596157134**)

So I tried to reload page twice and for the 1st reload it returns 404 and for the 2nd one - it returns 200. Here is log:

> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2016:11:46:24 +0000] "GET /product/am-0596157134 HTTP/1.1" 404 34 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
>
> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2016:11:46:25 +0000] "GET /product/am-0596157134 HTTP/1.1" 200 2299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"

Any ideas why it happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: Aside from my answer: don't you have a particular pattern (like `/product/*`) that all "Angular" requests will match? Using such a large regex seems overly complicated to me, and difficult to maintain.

Comment: In fact on server side I should know what routers can be, because it's job of angular 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** remove the `g` flag from the regular expression.

When you use `/g`, the regular expression keeps an internal state (stored in the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property) to be able to find successive matches.

In your case, this state is maintained between requests, so for the first request a match is performed, the last index gets updated, and when a new request comes in, matching starts from that last index. When it doesn't match (and it probably won't), the state it reset and a new request will match again.